# Call a class which extends PhoneStateListener in method "onCreate"

Tags: android

I I have a blink flashlight application, and would like to call the class which extends  PhoneStateListener in method "onCreate"

Here is the class which I want to call .. in order to light the flash during incoming call

How can I do that ?

---

```
 private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    // called when someone is ringing to this phone
                    getCamera();
                    turnOnFlash();

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```